# Python custom module import from module with only one public method

Tags: python, static-methods, python-decorators

Question regarding static methods and private methods....

Let's say I have something like this:

```
    class MyClass(object):

        @staticmethod
        def __methodA(a):
            return a

        @staticmethod
        def __methodB(b):
            return b

        @staticmethod
        def __methodC(c):
            return c

        @staticmethod
        def getAddition(a, b, c):
            a = MyClass.__methodA(a)
            b = MyClass.__methodB(b)
            c = MyClass.__methodC(c)
            return a + b + c
```

Where I really only want one method to be public and I have a whole bunch of helper methods. To me it seems silly to not have `@staticmethod` because then I have to do something like this:

```
from myModule import MyClass
myClass = MyClass()
myClass.getAddition(1,2,3)
```

but with @staticmethod I can just do this (which makes more sense to me since I'm only calling one thing):

```
from myModule import MyClass
MyClass.getAddition(1,2,3)
```

I know these types of questions have been asked before. But specifically I'm wondering if it's bad practice to do something like this with `@staticmethod` if I have let's say 50 helper methods and still only have the one public method.

This class would potentially be used by many people and I don't know if it makes sense to explicitly create that object for one method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine. Alternatively you can use module instead of class with static methods, because no need to create class, when you don't plan to create instances of it.

In the Python private methods is not restriction, but recommendation, therefore no need to restrict access to such methods. It's enough to denote this methods with underscore at the beginning.

Here is example with module instead of class:

```
// mymodule.py

def _methodA(a):
    return a

def _methodB(b):
    return b

def _methodC(c):
    return c

def getAddition(a, b, c):
    a = _methodA(a)
    b = _methodB(b)
    c = _methodC(c)
    return a + b + c

// user code

import mymodule

mymodule.getAddition(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: If I do that, others will be able to import things such as _methodC, which isn't what I want. I only want the users to be able to use one method.

Comment: Please, see the second paragraph of my answer: you absolutely cann't and shouldn't restrict access to methods. It's not Pythonic way of doing things. In you approach I can call you "private" methods like so `MyClass._MyClass__methodA(1)`.

Comment: @user2599709: Users can also access "private" static methods of a class. Code in any part of a program can access just about anything from anywhere else in the program, by design.

Comment: Oh believe me, I know we shouldn't. It's more of a...the helper methods are extremely powerful and dangerous if used solo, but the main method makes it so it's safe. I know there's no "private", but name mangling makes it "safe".

Comment: @user2599709: Uh... no it doesn't? It's not *hard* to access the mangled name. You just end up with an undocumented method with a name that tells you not to use it, the same way you would with a regular underscored name.

Comment: @user2357112, I know it's not the pythonic way of doing it and I myself am supposed to rely on the intelligence of the person using the API not to destroy their machine, but what if I want to make it so they have to go through more work to see they can destroy it? As a new person `MyClass.__methodA(1)` is going to appear under any IDE whereas `MyClass._MyClass__methodA(1)` will not.